# Add description to all extension less files in Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am searching a way to add a description to all the extension less files on my server (but not folders)

I started using something like this but it doesn't work:

```
<FilesMatch "^[^.]*$">
 AddDescription "This file has no extension" *.*
</FilesMatch>
```

EDIT: I found something interesting, but it selects folders and extensionless files at same time, and bring another question. If I add these two lines:

```
AddDescription "These are files with extensions" *.?
AddDescription "These are files without extension or Folders" *
```

As you see theses two instructions overlap themselves (the first line selects only files with extensions, and the second line selects all files with or without extensions as well as folders).

What I have difficulty to understand is that in this case the first line overrides the second line, so the description match well in my example.

And if I write:

```
AddDescription "These are files without extension or Folders" *
AddDescription "These are files with extensions" *.?
```

Then all files and folders get the description *"These are files without extension or Folders"* as the first line is overriding the second one. It is something very strange like code was executed from bottom to top.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Jck what doesnt work? Your code seems to append this description to all files. is this your issue?

Comment: @Starkeen The idea of what I'm trying to do is to append the description only to the files defined by the block directives.
In my case here, it seems that the block directives have no effect at all because AddDescription doesn't seem to work within block directives and on another hand, the wildcard `*.*` select all files _with_ extensions. For now it's just doing the opposite of what I want (it add descriptions to all files that have an extension, and leave the extension less files and folders unchanged). What I would like is adding the description only to extension less files.

Comment: I tried `AddDescription "mydesc" *.` but it selects all files with extensions. I also tried `AddDescription "mydesc" "^[^.]*$"` but it selects nothing.

Comment: sorry for the late reply to your comments, Actually I was very busy in my cousin ' s marriage. As far as I am aware AddDescription directive does not support regex in its second perameter. but wildcard expression is 100% supported. I know how to match a file with extension ( ***.php** ) but dont know how to match a file without extension , I am not good at wildcard expression. But I can give an idea to do that ,see #2 comment

Comment: if you want to add description to your files one by one


then you will have to add multiple AddDescription directive :

**AddDescription "name of this file is test" test**

**AddDescription "name of this file is foo" foo**

This will add description to 2 files **test** and **foo** .


<FilesMatch> is not needed, because AddDescription is already a file based directive

Comment: For more info ,please read 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html#addDescription

Comment: Jck the idea may seem boring but that's all I could do for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Starkeen. What I've found is that the correct wildcard to match extensionless files would be something like `!*.*` or `!*.?` in systems like DOS or UNIX, unfortunately Apache wildcard seems very basic and doesn't allow the `!` Btw It is not very important for my project and I can effectively add descriptions manually. I'll keep the question open if someone knows.

Comment: Shouldn't that dot be escaped for matching only a dot? Like `^[^\.]*$`